# How to tell MVC not to cache an aspx or ascx?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

In webforms I would do something like this in the OnInit method, but where (and how) could I do the same type of thing using MVC?

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the exact same thing in MVC too in the controller action (by writing the same line of code) or adding an attribute (which is preferred):

```
[OutputCache(Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]
public ActionResult Index() {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a non-MVC page in an MVC application, then the same way.  If you mean a particular action corresponding to a view, then use the OutputCacheAttribute on the action or controller with `Location = OutputCacheLocation.None`.